# `ie9` - contenteditable false not working when parent editable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, internet-explorer-9

I am trying to make a content editable and non-editable containers. the user can use this as 3 ways.

1. they can put content with `non-editable`
2. they can put the content with `editable`
3. they can put the content without selecting one of this. (editable)

I am trying to achieve this as follows:

```css
#content{
    border:1px solid red;
    height:100px;
}

.subContentNotEdit{
    background:#87a476;
}

.subContentEdit{
    background:#ffd5d5;
}
```

```html
<div id="content" contenteditable=true>
    <div class="subContentNotEdit" contenteditable=true>Editable</div>
    <div class="subContentEdit" contenteditable=false>Not editable</div>
    Enter text here..
</div>
```

Issue: in `ie9` still the `subContentNotEdit` div is editable. (i found that, because it's parent has the editable true!)

It works fine with `chrome` and `firefox`  but not in `ie9`. since my customer requires this option for `ie9` i am require to find a solution.

Can any one help me please?

Comment: It should work on IE9 actually, http://caniuse.com/#feat=contenteditable

Comment: yes, but nothing noted about the `parents` side effects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In IE it actually is working that the "false" flag is respected, but if you double-click on it, it goes into editmode (possibly because the double-click event bubbles up to the parent?).

My suggestion would be to put your non-editable content in an `::after` element (since no browser will find a caret position inside it to allow it to be edited) like so:

```css
#content{
    border:1px solid black;
    height:100px;
}

.subContentEdit{
    background:#87a476;
}

.subContentEdit::after {
    content:'Not editable';
    display:block;
    background:#ffd5d5;
}
```

```html
<div id="content" contenteditable="true">
    <div class="subContentEdit">Editable</div>
    Enter text here..
</div>
```