# Is there a way to convert a `class` based element to treat as single letter?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to a keep an text  became non-editable. still it's parent as `editable` mode. it's not working with `ie9` i have posted a question regarding here. But yet to get the suggestion.

[`ie9` - contenteditable false not working when parent editable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28854129/ie9-contenteditable-false-not-working-when-parent-editable)

But mean while, I searched and find a information says that,

```
Any element with the "mceNonEditable" class will be blocked from modifications and treated as a single character.
```

at here: http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Plugin:noneditable

But I am not in the position to use this plugin-now. since i have 600 pages+ with numerous instance need to replace. the site in `UAT` status.

Considering all, i looking for a solution, using `jQuery` to convert a `class` based element into single `letter` as like noted above.

Is it possible? if so any one have an idea to share?
Please help me.

Comment: Does it make any difference if you wrap it in an extra element whose contenteditable false flag is set so that its direct parent doesn't have editable set?

Comment: `var e = $('.class')` is it what you looking for?

Comment: @SteveK, can you look into my previous question to see the issue please?

Comment: @Jai i would like to add an class to editable parent, in which should not be an editable. - looking more info? let me know.